# A limit of trigonometric functions

Tags: limits

What is the lucky way to prove it without series expansion?

$$\lim_{x\to0}\displaystyle\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\right)}{\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}=1$$
Then I need to prove that 
$$\lim_{x\to0}\displaystyle\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}\right)}{\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}=\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: The best way I mean.

Comment: Hint:     $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\text{arctan}(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\text{sin}(x)}{x} = 1$.

Comment: @TomHarris I think those limits are equal to $1$

Comment: @LordSoth Cheers, fixed. Too keen!

Comment: @TomHarris that helps for the first limit. I think I know how to do it. Thank you. It remains the 2nd limit.

Comment: Given the value of your second limit though it looks like you can't just plug in the limit values, so I'd check the first one in detail.

Comment: @TomHarris you mean I have to apply the first result?

Comment: I mean if you put the values for the limits I gave in the hint into the first limit you get the correct answer but if you do the same for the second then you don't get the correct answer so this requires more thought about the limit. The original limits I gave will be of use though.

Comment: The series expansions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series) could also be useful.